# Changing A URL in a Iframe using a text box

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, navigation

I have a website http://speedie.mobi/emulator4/ and I would like to add a text box where people could add their own url to change what appears in the mobile phone.

It is just using a simple iframe browser.

So by adding their url in the text box it would replace the current url with their url.

Quentin

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
    function goTo() {
        var input = get("box").value,
            frame = get("frame");

        if(input.match(/\bhttp(.)*/)) {
            frame.src = input;
        } else {
            input = "http://" + input;
            frame.src = input;
        }      
    }

    function get(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);    
    }  
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="box" value="http://www.example.com" />
<button onClick="goTo();">go</button>

<iframe src="http://www.example.com" frameborder="0" id="frame" width="100%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

### --> [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sJjJN/1/) <--

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery,

```
var url = $('#urltext').value();
$('#targetframe').attr('src',url);>
```